# How to change default selected focused background color in ListView in UWP?

Tags: windows, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp

I am  working on windows universal app. I want to change my  list view selected background color.The system default selected background   color is blue and i need a gray color.I used a data template for binding data to listview.

Code

Datatemplate

```
<Page.Resources>
<DataTemplate x:Name="datatemplate1" x:DataType="data:storedata">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>

                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                           Text="{x:Bind name}" 
                           x:Phase="1"  
                           x:Name="product_name_layout"
                           Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"
                           TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
                            Foreground="#FF080808"                                                 
                           Margin="2,3,0,0"
                           FontSize="12"
                           />
                <TextBlock x:Name="status_title_layout"    FontSize="12" Foreground="Gray"   Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"    Visibility="Visible"  SelectionHighlightColor="#FFB1B4BE" Margin="2,5,0,0" Text="SKU:" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock  Grid.Column="1"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Text="{x:Bind status}" 
                            x:Phase="2"
                            Foreground="Gray"
                             FontSize="12"
                             Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"
                            Margin="32,5,0,0"
                            x:Name="sku_layout"/>

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>
```

ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="MasterListView"                 
                  UseLayoutRounding="False"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"                 
                  BorderBrush="#FFA70EAA"
                  SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged"
                  IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                  ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="False"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource datatemplate1 }"
                  ItemClick="OnItemClick"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                    >

            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>


                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"  Value="Stretch" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

        </ListView>
```

I also Put some Screen shot so you can easily understand.

Image

[image: List view issue]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to your ListViewItem's style this template:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
      <ListViewItemPresenter
          ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
          SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="True"
          CheckBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
          CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
          DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}"
          DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}"
          FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltHighBrush}"
          FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
          PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"
          PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}"
          PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"
          SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}"
          SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"
          SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush}"
          PressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush}"
          SelectedPressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush}"
          DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
          DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}"
          ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
          HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
          VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
          ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
          CheckMode="Inline"/>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Here you can delete or modify what you want, it looks like you want to change SelectedBackground color to DarkGrey.

Comment: I just edited code like this                                                      SelectedBackground="DarkGrey"      But its not worked.

Comment: Thank You so much for providing best solution.can you please suggest me one thing. I have 20 Listview in my application and i want to apply this thing to all listview then  how can i generalize the style so each and every Listview affected by this style.

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot rewrite original ListView Template, you have to put this style to every ListView. The best thing will be if you put this style to App.xaml file and then you can use it everywhere without any references.